# Magento 2 Mulitwebsite not loading CSS Js and images

Tags: magento2, css, multistore, multi-website

I have a website in IP format like `12.34.56.78`

with multi-website like this -

```
12.34.56.78/dev1

12.34.56.78/dev2

12.34.56.78/dev3

12.34.56.78/dev4
```

I created Folder in Magento root directory **dev1,dev2,dev3 & dev4** and inside that folder, I add **index.php,.htaccess file, and symlinks of app, lib, pub & var.**

All is working **fine**.

Now I point IP to Domain name, Main website **abc.com** is perfectly working fine but

```
abc.com/dev1
abc.com/dev2
abc.com/dev3
abc.com/dev4
```

is not working when I open **abc.com/dev1** website open but **CSS, JS, and images** not loading.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: check console you get more idea, why its not loading,

Comment: @Yogesh it showing net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: remove symlinks for one website and create again

Comment: do you have idea how to remove symlinks ?

Comment: go that folder and delete that and recreate it.

Comment: @Yogesh delete symlinks and again create but still problem not solved

Comment: Check your nginx or apache server configuration

Comment: @kunj what i have to check in apache server configuration

Comment: Check apache configuration is proper for multi-website OR you need a different domain for multi-website and no need folders for each website just configure it proper for examples. https://www.ubertheme.com/magento2/setting-up-magento-2-multi-stores-tutorial-part-2/
https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/set-multiple-websites-apache/

Comment: @kunj but i need to show my stores like this - abc.com/dev1,abc.com/dev2 etc...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution

I've www.abc.com pointing to my doc root where the code base lives. In the doc root, I've got a subdir named dev1. In Magento, I've created a new website and set the base URLs for the new website to www.abc.com/dev1/. I need to set the static and media files base URLs to 'www.abc.com/pub/static/' and 'www.abc.com/pub/media/', respectively, otherwise the css and js was not loading.

Refrence - https://gist.github.com/thagxt/0f605f0a8a95c79302db0d2f04383788